# Is the matrix of a Hermitian operator on a finite dimensional vector space always Hermitian regardless of the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products, hermitian-matrices

I'm trying to prove that if an operator $U$ is Hermitian, then its corresponding matrix in an arbitrary basis $U_{ij}$ satisfies $U_{ij}^* = U_{ji}$, but it seems like that's only possible if the basis is orthonormal. Is this false?

Comment: Choosing a basis only gives a matrix representation to an abstract linear transformation.

Comment: That is true. However I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: To define the concept of orthogonality, we need to define an inner product, firstly. So all conclusion for the matrix representations depends on the basis vectors and the inner product we choose.

Comment: Note that the condition you are stating is that of a *Hermitian* matrix, not a unitary one. I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a complex inner product space and $f\colon V\to V$ a Hermitian operator, that is $$\langle f(v),w\rangle = \langle v,f(w)\rangle.$$

Given a basis $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ and denoting by $[v]_B\in\mathbb C^n$ the coordinate vector of $v\in V$, the operator $f$ corresponds to the matrix
$$
[f]_B = \left.\bigg(\,[f(v_1)]_B\ \middle|\ \cdots\ \middle|\ [f(v_n)]_B\,\right).
$$
Denote by $G_B=(\langle v_i, v_j\rangle)_{i,j}$ the Gramian matrix of the inner product with respect to the basis $B$, then
$$
\langle v,w \rangle = [v]_B^\dagger \,G_B\, [w]_B,
$$
where $M^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose of a complex matrix $M$.

Hence, the fact that $f$ is Hermitian translates to
$$
[f(v)]_B^\dagger\, G_B\, [w]_B = [v]_B^\dagger\, G_B\, [f(w)]_B,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
[v]_B^\dagger\, [f]_B^\dagger\, G_B\, [w]_B = [v]_B^\dagger\, G_B\, [f]_B\, [w]_B.
$$
Letting $v$ and $w$ run through the basis vectors of $B$, this becomes
$$
[f]_B^\dagger\, G_B = G_B\, [f]_B.
$$

If $B$ is an orthonormal basis, the Gram matrix $G_B$ is the identity matrix and this condition becomes $[f]_B^\dagger = [f]_B$. So in this case $f$ is Hermitian if and only if $[f]_B$ is a Hermitian matrix.

If $B$ is not an orthonormal basis, the Gramian matrix $G_B$ is just any positive definite Hermitian matrix and the condition doesn't simplify. Hermitian operators do not correspond to Hermitian matrices any longer.